# Stub standalone function from JSON module in Sinon

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

code.js

```
const fun = () => {
  console.log('Some message');
}

module.exports = {fun}
```

file.js

```
const {fun} = require('./code');

const abc = () => { 
  return fun();
}

module.exports = {abc}
```

file.test.js

```
const code = require('./code');
const abc = require('./abc');
const sinon = require('sinon');

it('Should return Some Message', () => {
  sinon.stub(code,'fun').returns(true);
  abc.abc();
});
```

Here, I want to stub the function `fun` but as I'm importing it in a different way than an object, the stubbing is not working.

I don't want to change my importing style to an object instead of importing selective keys.

Is there any way to do the stubbing in Sinon?

Answer (score 0):

You should call `sinon.stub()` before `require('./abc')`:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const code = require('./code');
sinon.stub(code,'fun').returns(true);
const abc = require('./abc');

it('Should return Some Message', () => {
    abc.abc();
});
```